# Instead of using a lot of java code, why not send a script to DB in the form of text file?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I was thinking that doing java code for executing DDL, DML etc is cumbersome and involves a lot of typing. So, I was thinking if databases have/can be made to have the following feature -Take a script in a text file and execute the entire script.

If we had something like this, then we could type our SQL queries into a text file in the usual, easy way. The java code then sends this text file to the DB which executes it as if someone had typed the script into its management GUI.

Is this possible ? What could be the disadvantages of such a system ?

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much every database I am aware of has such a capability (including MySQL mentioned in your tag).  You simply do something like this from a command line client (this example for MySQL)

```
mysql -h hostname -u user < sql_script.sql
```

There is no middle layer of using some programming language to pass the file.

Answer (score 3):

I would say go for it for your DDL.  I always drop my table/index/constraint creations in a SQL script and run it to setup my database.

However, for DML, like other posters have said, you will be doing these queries often (usually) based off of user input.  If the user creates some object in your system, you will end up saving it with one or more inserts/updates.  The parameters to those statements will be the values the user entered into your system.  It will be more maintainable and easier to understand if you use Java's facilities for executing these directly.  Trying to replace tokens in a SQL file with the parameters and passing it to the database would quickly become more cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

What you suggest is essentially something like evoking Stored Procedures on the RDBMS.

The disadvtantage being that your domain-logic now resides in your persistence-layer which is (can be) bad for several reasons.

One of the main problems being: **code maintenance**: programmer nightmare from maintenance standpoint as well as programmers requiring skill in both domani logic as well as sql-statements. Depending on the size of your team, this may be a big concern. Generally adhere to the rule **Separation of Concerns**

Comment: what do you mean by persistence layer ?

Comment: Traditionally well-designed apps have a presentation layer (for UI-logic stuff), a business layer (for business logic, transactional stuff), and a persistence layer (which is used to save data in the DB and retrieve data from the DB).

Answer (score 1):

You need statements in Java code because most of the values sent as parameters are only known at runtime: they come from the GUI, and from all the business code executed between each query. Otherwise, yes, what you want exists: they're called stored procedures.